# array merging using loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I know this is easy to think but don't know how to translate it to code. I have 2 sets of array (a header and a body) that goes like this:

```
HEADER
'tfa_1' => string '(First, Middle, Last)' (length=21)
  'tfa_10' => string 'Card Type' (length=9)
  'tfa_11' => string 'Diners Club' (length=11)
  'tfa_12' => string 'MasterCard' (length=10)
  'tfa_3' => string 'Last 4 Digits of Card Number' (length=28)
  'tfa_127' => string 'Email Address' (length=13)
  'tfa_150' => string 'Phone Number' (length=12)
  'tfa_156' => string 'What type of phone number is this?' (length=34)
  'tfa_157' => string 'Mobile Number' (length=13)
  'tfa_158' => string 'Landline Number' (length=15)
  'tfa_128' => string 'When is the best time to call you for verification?' (length=51) 

BODY
 'tfa_1' => string 'Mike' (length=18)
  'tfa_10' => string 'MasterCard' (length=10)
  'tfa_3' => string '123' (length=4)
  'tfa_127' => string 'mike@yahoo.com' (length=22)
  'tfa_150' => string '09xxxxxx' (length=11)
  'tfa_156' => string 'Mobile Number' (length=13)
```

I need it to be like this:

```
 'tfa_1' => string 'mike' (length=21)
      'tfa_10' => string 'MasterCard' (length=9)
      'tfa_11' => string '' (length=11)
      'tfa_12' => string '' (length=10)
      'tfa_3' => string '123' (length=28)
      'tfa_127' => string 'mike@yahoo.com' (length=13)
      'tfa_150' => string 'P09xxxxxx' (length=12)
      'tfa_156' => string 'Mobile Number' (length=34)
      'tfa_157' => string '' (length=13)
      'tfa_158' => string '' (length=15)
      'tfa_128' => string ''
```

I tried

```
$merge = (array_merge($header,$body));
```

successful but I need those that $body have not response should on a specific key should be NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If key exists, add the value else fill the empty value..

`$data` will have what you need. I assume `$header` is the header array and `$body` is the body array.

```
  $data=array();  
  foreach($header as $key=>$value){
  if (array_key_exists($key, $body)) 
    $data[key]=$body[$key];
  else
    $data[key]="";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use

```
$arrayMerge = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

If you will dump `$arrayMerge` then it contains the duplicate values.

You can use `array_unique($arrayMerge);`

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I needed those that have no key in the body should be NULL in the header